# Passing data from a controller to ChartJS - Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I would like to pass data from my laravel controller to chartjs javascript file.  But at the moment, I can only get the data to home.blade and not the javascript file.
below is my controller:

```
 public function index()
{


    $visits = Visitdetail::all();
    $countVisit = $visits->count();


    $totalSchools = School::all()->count();
    $totalProjects = Project::all()->count();

    $recentVisits = Visitdetail::all()->sortByDesc('created_at')->take(5);


    $visitsYear = Visit::where('created_at','>=', Carbon::now()->startOfYear())->take(5)->get();





    return view('home',['countVisit'=>$countVisit,'recentVisits'=>$recentVisits, 'totalSchools'=>$totalSchools,'totalProjects'=>$totalProjects,
        'yearVisits'=>$visitsYear]);
}
```

On home.blade, I just have a canvas and the below is the code:

```
<div class="box-body">                    
  <div class="chart">
     <canvas id="barChart" style="height:227px"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the chartJS file, I have the following code (Filename: dashboard.js), located in the public/js/dashboard.js directory:

```
// Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
    var barChartCanvas = $('#barChart').get(0).getContext('2d');
    // This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
    var barChart            = new Chart(barChartCanvas);

    var barChartData = {
      labels  : ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label               : 'Electronics',
          fillColor           : 'rgba(38,198,218,1)',
          strokeColor         : 'rgba(38,198,218,0)',
          pointColor          : '#26c6da',
          pointStrokeColor    : 'rgba(38,198,218,0)',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(38,198,218,1)',
          data                : [5, 4, 3, 7, 5, 10, 3]
        },
        {
          label               : 'Digital Goods',
          fillColor           : 'rgba(30,136,229,1)',
          strokeColor         : 'rgba(30,136,229,0)',
          pointColor          : 'rgba(30,136,229,0)',
          pointStrokeColor    : '#1e88e5',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(30,136,229,1)',
          data                : [3, 2, 9, 5, 4, 6, 4]
        }
      ]
    };
```

I tried to set the values of the  the dataset with dynamic blade variable, where on data, I had:

```
data                : [{{$countVisits}}, {{recentVisits}}]
```

However, this didn't work. Any assistance that could point me to the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: `{Model}::all()->count();` is redundant; just do `{Model}::count();` Both the `Builder` and `Collection` classes (result of `::all()`) have a method `count()`, so might as well not use the extra resources to fetch all records before counting them.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks! I'll rectify that

Comment: No problem! Secondly, `blade` syntax, like `{{ }}` won't work in a `.js` file. If you had this in a `<script>` element inside a `.blade.php` file, then you'd be able to use `{{ $countsVisits }}`, etc., but currently, you're going to have to assign these PHP values to JS variables before trying to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert a variable from Laravel into an asset file. You can only insert in views. Assets are supposed to be the part that doesn't change across requests.

The usual way is to insert the data in the view and store it in a global JS variable that the script can access.

I.e. in `home.blade.php` do this:

```js
<script>
var datasets = [@json($countVisits), @json($recentVisits)]

// or using an object
var theDatasets = {
    countVisits: @json($countVisits),
    recentVisits: @json($recentVisits)
}

//or directly
var countVisits = @json($countVisits)
var recentVisits = @json($recentVisits)
</script>

<!-- include your dashboard.js afterwards -->
```

And then you can use the variable inside the `dashboard.js` in a way that corresponds to how you stored it:

```js
//from array
datasets[0]

//from object
theDatasets.countVisits

//directly
countVisits
```

The other ways to solve this would be

- load data via AJAX. But this shifts the problem that you have to give or hardcode the route
- put all that chart javascript in the view (I would do this if it's only used in one view, you can also include it from a subview if you want the code organized)
- create the javascript file as a dynamic view and let blade insert the data into it. I have never seen this done and it doesn't seem appropriate, but it's probably possible.